# IPsec: hide private IP behind Gateway IP

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, iptables, nat, ipsec

I have an IPsec Gateway to a customer, and the VPN tunnel is up, the problem is that they don't allow me to use my private address because it used by another VPN they use. Our gateway is an EC2 instance hosted in Amazon Cloud with public Elastic IP:

My side gw: 10.0.3.22 --> Elastic IP: 1.1.1.1 --> Their IPsec gw 2.2.2.2

I have to connect to a server 3.3.3.3 behind their IPsec gw, and when I try packets don't go back:

```
$ telnet 3.3.3.3 443 (the only opened port)
10.0.3.22 > 2.2.2.2 (ESP traffic, seq=0x1)
10.0.3.22 > 2.2.2.2 (ESP traffic, seq=0x2)
... until timeout
```

The customer can confirm that VPN tunnel is up, and they see the traffic in their logs, but is dropped before reach 3.3.3.3 by their firewall. They will accept 1.1.1.1 as source only. So I have to hide my private IP 10.0.3.22 with a NAT to 1.1.1.1.

Is this possible using iptables? I tried to do SNAT and DNAT but it doesn't work:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 1.1.1.1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.22
```